# How to parse JSON Array and stored in arraylist in java?

Tags: java, json

I want to parse following JSON array and store in array list.

```
[{"type":{"Male":"1","Female":"2"}}]
```

I have tried following code

```
JSONObject object=getJSONObject(0).getString("type");
```

Result:

```
{"Male":"1","Female":"2"}
```

Here type is the key and others are values.

It comes with comma, quotes.How to store this values are in `ArrayList`?

Comment: In an `ArrayList`? Do you mean `Map`?

Comment: see [this](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Primitives-Examples)..you will be able to understand the whole thing..

Comment: @Thanks kepil.yes.because i want to store both values male and 1 values.so better map will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below should do the trick for your JSON. Seeing your JSON I don't see an Array anywhere.

```
String resultJson; // Assuming this has the JSON given in the question.
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(resultJson);
JSONObject type = object.getJSONObject("type"); //Get the type object.

HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); //Creating the Map

String male = type.getString("male"); //Get the male value
String female = type.getString("female"); //Get the female value

map.put("male", Integer.parseInt(male));
map.put("female", Integer.parseInt(female));
```

Comment: no.dont use male and female as key.because based on type value it can changed.so type only static.

Comment: You can change that as per your needs. I've just given a sample code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();     

if (jsonArray != null) {          //In this case jsonArray is your JSON array
   int len = jsonArray.length();
   for (int i=0;i<len;i++){ 
       list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
   } 
}
```

Comment: @thanks.It returns {"Male":"1","Female":"2"} whole part.How to remove para-this,comma,quotes?